# Is there a way to rotate multiple photos at once in the camera roll?

Tags: iphone, photos, ios

In iOS on the iPhone I only see a way to select one photo at once in order to then rotate it in the Photos app.

Is there a method or perhaps a third-party app that could perform this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this without a third-party app or a shortcut at the moment.

- If you have a Mac and you are using iCloud Photos sync, you can do it in the Photos app
- If you're ready to pay for an app, [OneEdit Pro](https://apps.apple.com/app/oneedit-pro/id405952381) will do the job
- You can also use a shortcut like this one : [Batch Rotate Images](https://shortcutsgallery.com/shortcuts/batch-rotate-images/)